# HERE EV Charging Station API is giving error : Forbidden (403)

Tags: here-api

I am trying to use HERE api to get some charging station data. I signed up for a freemium account and verified my email address and added credit card information. I am using Postman to send requests but unfortunately I get the error " These credentials do not authorize access". I am not sure why I am getting this error. I got my API key.

Getting response as below:
"error": "Forbidden",
"error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"

Answer (score 0):

EV Charging Station API is not supported with our Lite & Explore SDK edition (refer screenshot atttached). Please review our plan vs feature dashboard at https://developer.here.com/plan-features. Do let us know if you are trying to use the API with REST, JavaScript or Premium SDK - share the AppID details to investigate further.[image]